# SQL Server 2008 error: Incorrect sytax near a character that's not in my statement

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

Using vbscript to process a form in classic ASP, I create the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [RemitChangeControl].[dbo].[FormData]
VALUES
(142, 2, 'asdfasdf');
```

I get this error:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 error '80040e14'

Incorrect syntax near '<'.
```

This strange because no where in my insert statement is the character `'<'` found.  So how could there be an error near a non-existent character?

Oddly enough, if I create the same statement by including it directly in my code as a literal string, it works correctly.

Comment: Can you add a trace on SQL Server to see what the ASP site is actually sending to SQL Server?  I'd be curious what it is actually sending...

Comment: Obviously the query that you are running doesn't look at all what you think, so it's not so useful to only see what you think that the query looks like. What does the code that creates the query look like?

Comment: @Michael  I'm trying to figure out how to set up a trace on SQL Server.  Do you know where I can read documentation for that?  Otherwise I'll have to wait for a DBA to be in on Monday.

Comment: @Guffa  I agree that the query I am running doesn't look like I think it does.  I'll post code as to how I generate the query as soon as I can.

Comment: Have you tried printing the statement after creating it in your vbscript code?

Comment: @ypercube  Yes, the insert statement in my question is from a print that runs right before I try to execute it.

Comment: Can you try (just in case) removing the semicolon at the end?

Comment: @ypercube  I was certain it was not caused by the semicolon but tried it anyway.  The semicolon is not the problem.

Comment: Figured it out.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code I used for debugging another issue caused my problem.  Specifically, I misunderstood VBScript parameter passing and assignment semantics.

Here's the code that runs the insert statement:

```
insert_statement = INSERT INTO [RemitChangeControl].[dbo].[FormData]" & vbcrlf _
    & "VALUES " & vbcrlf _
    & join(value_clauses.Items, "," & vbcrlf) & ";"

write_to_web_page insert_statement ' OOPS!
objconn.Execute insert_statement
```

Here's the function that it was calling:

```
sub write_to_web_page(s)
    ' assigment to s mutates it!
    s = Replace(Server.HTMLEncode(s), vbcrlf, "<br />")
    response.write("<p>" & t & "</p>")
end sub
```

When I pass `insert_statement` to `write_to_web_page` it is passed by reference.  When I reassign the result of `Replace` to the local variable it mutates in the caller, resulting in `insert_statment` containing a number of `"<br />"`.  That's what I get for expecting Python assignment semantics in VBScript.

I finally figured this out while chopping my code down to size to flesh out my question here.  Suprisingly, my small example did not exhibit the bug.  I then inserted calls to `write_to_web_page` to figure out what was going on.  Then my bug reappeared and the light bulb went on.

Comment: Yeah, by default arguments are passed by reference so will modify the original variable as well.

Comment: @Ryan  My language of choice, Python, has pass-by-reference semantics (actually, it binds objects passed to the local name), but assignment does not mutate an object, it rebinds a name.  The only way an object mutates in python is if you call a function that mutates it.  In vbscript, assignment copies to the memory location pointed to by the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick tutorial on setting up a trace using SQL Server Management Studio and Profiler:

http://www.petri.co.il/monitoring-with-sql-profiler.htm

Comment: +1.  Unfortunately the SQL Server Profiler was not installed with my SQL Server Management Studio and I do not have access to any installation media to rectify the issue.  Still, it's a good suggestion.